# symfony entityType translate choice_label within var

Tags: symfony

How can I translate the choice_label of a entityType field within var in the string?

```
$builder->add('shippingAddress', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class'    => 'LilWorksStoreBundle:Address' ,
                    'choice_label' => function ($obj) {
                        return    "String to translate with " . $obj->getName()  ;
                    },
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($customer) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                            ->leftJoin('LilWorksStoreBundle:Customer', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = a.customer')
                            ->where('c.id = :id')
                            ->setParameter('id',$customer->getId())
                            ;
                    },
                    'required' => false ,
                    'mapped'=> true,
                    'expanded' => true ,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'translation_domain' => 'my_translation'
                ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
'choice_translation_domain' => 'my_translation'
```

Comment: Thanks... But how can I had some var for transchoice?

Comment: Yes, thats an interesting question. Did you do that?